# Meteor wrapAsync

Tags: asynchronous, meteor

I'm trying to implement the following scenario:
1. Client calls a meteor-method.
2. Inside the meteor-method i make an HTTP-Post to a different server.
3. When the HTTP-Call is responded, the meteor method should return true and in the case an error occurs it should return false.

Here is what my meteor method looks like:

```
uploadUserImage: function(data_url,userid) {
    asyncfnc =function(data,uid){
        HTTP.post("http://localhost:2000/upload", {
            data: {
                "data_url": data,
                "user_id": uid
            }
        },function(err,res){
            console.log(res);
            if (err){
                console.log("error");
                throw new Error(err.message);
            }
            else{
                console.log("return true");
                return true;
            }
        });
    };
    var waitForResult = Meteor.wrapAsync(asyncfnc);
    var result = waitForResult(data_url,userid);
    return result;
}
```

The HTTP-Call works and I also get into the Callback of the HTTP.post-function.
But on the clientside where I called the meteor-method i don't get into my callback-function. It looks like this:

```
Meteor.call("uploadUserImage",data_url,Session.get("newUserID"),function (err, res) {
       if(err){
           console.log(err);
       } else {
           console.log('response: ', res);
       }
 });
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is my meteor-method not returning anything?
Is everything correct with my Meteor.wrapAsync()?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you get some errors?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution, which does not require Meteor.wrapAsync().

```
 var url = "http://localhost:2000/upload";
    //synchronous GET
    var result = Meteor.http.post(url,{
                data: {
                    "title": "i want to upload a picture",
                    "data_url": data_url,
                    "user_id": userid
                },timeout:30000});
    if(result.statusCode==200) {
        console.log(result);
        console.log("response received.");
        return result;
    } else {
        console.log("Response issue: ", result.statusCode);
        var errorJson = JSON.parse(result.content);
        throw new Meteor.Error(result.statusCode, errorJson.error);
    }
```

This makes the HTTP-Post-Call synchronous, so there is no need to wrap async.

Comment: your answer still async... no guarantee to make sync just with timeout.. what if your method have multiple call from multiple user... your timeout will useless..

Comment: you think that this.unblock() could do this?

Comment: you need `Meteor.wrapAsync()`... `this.unblock()` only prevent your method blocking other method or subscription when your method being called... there is nothing to do with sync call..

Comment: could you please post an answer with Meteor.wrapAsync() for my question?

Comment: i'm successfully sync call linkedin, github, and geo google api with `Meteor.wrapAsync()`... they're `call`... i don't know when it come to `post`... i'm sorry,,,

Answer (score 0):

You are asking too much in this situation.
Meteor methods can be called synchronously, but it's not advisable if the method is doing a remote call like this.

My feeling is that you are hanging on to a procedural programming model where you want a synchronous result to 1) a call to your server, and 2) a request sent to another remote server. And you want to get a return value from your call. It doesn't work like that.

Meteor protects you to a large degree from dealing with asynchronicity, but sometimes you have to accept that a little more work is required to deal with it correctly.

So my recommendation is to use callbacks for notification.